# New PhoneGap 3.0 The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved

Tags: java, javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

I'm installing the new phone gap 3.0 with the all-mighty command line.

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cordova platform add android
```

When I open the android project in eclipse I get this error on `HelloWorld.java`:

```
The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved
```

I guess I have a missing library but how to I solve this if the only way to install 3.0 is thought the command line.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:** If you upgrade to Phonegap 3.3 you shouldn't need to do this anymore. Details on updating Phonegap: **http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/12/13/phonegap-release/**

**Note:** Make sure in eclipse you import **Existing Android Code into Workspace** NOT 'Existing Projects into Workspace

I had the exact same problem and found a solution that works:

1. Download the source ZIP for Cordova:
   **http://cordova.apache.org/#download**
2. Extract the 'cordova-android'
   ZIP anywhere. Inside will be a 'framework' folder.
3. In eclipse open the newly unzipped 'cordova-android/framework'
   folder as an existing project.
4. In eclipse right click on this new 'Cordova'
   **project -> Properties -> Android** . Make sure 'Is Library' is checked.
5. Right click on your app's **project -> Properties -> Android**. In
   the Library section choose 'Add'. Select your Cordova project.

All done, import should now resolve!