# Phonegap 3.3 Eclipse: -CordovaLib project missing Android properties

Tags: android, eclipse, properties, shared-libraries, cordova-3

Trying to import new PhoneGap 3.3 project into Eclipse 4.3.1 - after initial phonegap CLI build I import 2 projects (HelloWorld and HelloWorld-CordovaLib). I get "The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved" error as CordovaLib seems not to be linked as library to the HelloWorld project.

However, I am not able to flag the CordovaLib project in its Android properties as "Is library" (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097370/new-phonegap-3-0-the-import-org-apache-cordova-cannot-be-resolved) post) because there is no Android section in its properties (the project seems not to behave as Android one). The Android properties of my HelloWorld shows CordovaLib in Library section but is has a red cross next to it. What should I do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solved by not choosing "Copy projects into workspace" when importing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Additionally, I had to do "Build Project" on the CordovaLib, to get rid of "null-CordovaLib.jar" not found error.

Comment: cmd:> cd path/to/my-app Enter then cmd:> phonegap platform update android  Enter then copy project into desktop and import to eclipse. It's working.

Comment: This was my issue as well, it seems that some of the build process is hard coded with relative paths that get broken...