# Downgrade Phonegap android version from 3.40 to 2.9.0

Tags: android, testing, cordova

I am using `phonegap 3.4.0` version for my android app project. My app is working fine in this version. Now, I want to test my app in cordova `version 2.9.0`. I have searched net and haven't get a grip on this issue.

My question is, **how do i downgrade my phonegap version 3.4.0 to phonegap version 2.9.0?** 
also, cordova library is not showing up in my eclipse after changing version to 2.9.0. Without CordovaLib the project will not run. **What should do to add CordovaLib in my app?**

Comment: Why, exactly, do you want to test in 2.9.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To downgrade my phonegap version 3.4.0 to phonegap version 2.9.0, I used the below command line interface:

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova@2.9.0
```

This [Link](http://outof.me/embedding-cordovalib-in-your-iosphonegap-app-project/) helps me to add CordovaLib in both ios and android.

REF: [Phonegap 3.3 Eclipse: -CordovaLib project missing Android properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703463/phonegap-3-3-eclipse-cordovalib-project-missing-android-properties)

Answer (score 0):

npm install -g phonegap@2.9.0-rc1-0.12.2