# PhoneGap 3.3 The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Running on Windows 7, I have a PhoneGap 2.6 app that I want to bring up to date with PhoneGap 3.3. I thought I would download/install 3.3 and essentially copy in all my files into a new project and then build the new app. I believe I have installed all that is necessary (took 2 days of grief and agony). I use the CLI to create a new project, add Android, and build (I can successfully run it on my devices). I then go into Eclipse and select New Project From Existing Code, pointing to the dir that holds my CLI-build project. I do *not* copy files into the workspace, because they are already in the right place, and everyone else on the web says do *not* copy files when creating from existing code.

In any case, once I've identified the dir to do New Project from, I get *two* projects that are nominated to be added:  platforms\android with a name of: MyProject and platforms\android\CordovaLib with a name of MyProject-CordovaLib. Not knowing any better, I allow both 'projects' to be 'imported' (or whatever the verb would be there). I have also tried *not* importing the second project, but that does not seem to matter.

Upon creating the project(s), I get an error in my 'desired' project: 'import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved', just like many others have reported across many other versions of PhoneGap. I have tried setting the Android properties to the latest API and cleaning, but that does nothing.

I can see that the 'libs' folder is empty, whereas in my old 2.6 project, it contained the cordova-2.6.0.jar file. From what I have read on other posts of this nature, the .jar file is no longer part of the PhoneGap download/install. Something about the 'Add New Project' or the earlier 'build' effort is not generating the file. I have gone to the Apache site and downloaded their source, i.e., I have the Android Framework stuff. I am not sure how to get from what I have to a build-able project. Clearly I do not want/need to have a 'project' for MyProject-CordovaLib, but I am not sure what to do next.

Thanks in advance,

-David

Answer (score 4):

you will need a reference to the "Framework" folder of the extracted Cordova files as a Library Project in the workspace:

[New PhoneGap 3.0 The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097370/new-phonegap-3-0-the-import-org-apache-cordova-cannot-be-resolved)

1. Download the source ZIP for Cordova:
   http://cordova.apache.org/#download
2. Extract the 'cordova-android'
   ZIP anywhere. Inside will be a 'framework' folder.
3. In eclipse open the newly unzipped 'cordova-android/framework' folder as an existing
   project.
4. In eclipse right click on this new 'Cordova' project ->
   Properties -> Android . Make sure 'Is Library' is checked.
5. Right click on your app's project -> Properties -> Android. In the Library
   section choose 'Add'. Select your Cordova project.

Comment: This actually worked for android cordova 3.4.0. Cheers, mate.

Comment: These steps work well with the cordova-android-4.0.2.tgz file located at https://www.apache.org/dist/cordova/platforms/. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I started with the 2 projects (the desired project and the "*-CordovaLib" one) and I had the same issue.

Cleaning projects contributed to resolving the issue, but what finally resolved it was to build manually first the *-CordovaLib project (try it just after cleaning). After that, building and running my project worked fine.

Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at my question and quest for upgrading... [Upgrade to phonegap 3.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923738/upgrade-to-phonegap-3-3-0)

It seems I had the same problem...